# comma within paste in R

Tags: r, paste

I would like to paste something that has "" within.

```
> i = 4
> paste("var", i, "option="juk"", "--opt2 12")

Error: unexpected symbol in "paste("var", i, "option="juk"
```

What the pasted phrase should look like (which included comma within)

```
var 4 option = "juk" --opt2 12
```

Is there any way to solve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be

```
(x <- paste("var", i, 'option="juk"', "--opt2 12"))
# [1] "var 4 option=\"juk\" --opt2 12"
cat(x)
# var 4 option="juk" --opt2 12
```