# how do I change a number inside ""?

Tags: r

I am trying to read a bunch of CSV files. this files are under separate folders. All the CSV  files have same name but they are under folders with different time and date.

I need to ran a for loop to be able to import the data sets. My question is - how do I change a number inside "" ?

```
for (i in 0:23)
path= file.path("2017-02-23 i_00_00/Registrations.csv")

setwd("C:/Users/psnitu/Desktop/toy data")
path= file.path("2017-02-23 05_00_00/Registrations.csv")
data1= read.table(path, header = F, sep=",")
```

Comment: `path= file.path(paste0("2017-02-23 ", i, "_00_00/Registrations.csv")`

Comment: if you have a parent folder containing your date/time folders, you can just use `list.files(path = "D:/data/",pattern = "Registration.csv",recursive=TRUE,full.names=TRUE)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [comma within paste in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35779204/comma-within-paste-in-r)

Comment: You could also use `sprintf` like this: `sprintf("%s%02d%s","2017-02-23 ",0:23,"_00_00/Registrations.csv")`

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
 for (i in 0:23)
  path= file.path(paste0("2017-02-23 ",i,"_00_00/Registrations.csv"))
```

Comment: Bear in mind that sometimes whitespace in names will give you hard time